# Gettig RedisOutOfMemoryException

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I am using Reddison to set the TTL for the keys of a HashMap.

This works correctly. But while inserting a large amount of data,like 5 million in 30 min, the data still remains in Redis and does not expire.
The Database Memory Usage Percentage reaches 100% after few iterations in AWS ElasticCache

Below is the code which I am using in the sprint boot code implementation and getting and exception

CODE:

```
RMapCache<String, Object> map = getConnection().getMapCache(mapName);
map.put(key, obj, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

EXCEPTION:

```
org.redisson.client.RedisOutOfMemoryException: command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'. script: 8002ee0f772fdaac4335bffe445fb53aef8dcd57, on @user_script:1.. channel: [id: 0x17227def, L:/10.224.59.44:59436 - R:10.224.57.111/10.224.57.111:6379] data: CommandData [promise=java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@120fc639[Not completed, 1 dependents], command=(EVAL), params=[local insertable = false; local v = redis.call('hget', KEYS[1], ARGV[5]); if v == false then insertable = true; else local t, val = struct.unpack('dLc0', v); local expireDate = 92233720368547758; local expireDateScore = redis.call('zscore', KEYS[2], ARGV[5]); if expireDateScore ~= false then expireDate = tonumber(expireDateScore) end; if t ~= 0 then local expireIdle = redis.call('zscore', KEYS[3], ARGV[5]); if expireIdle ~= false then expireDate = math.min(expireDate, tonumber(expireIdle)) end; end; if expireDate <= tonumber(ARGV[1]) then insertable = true; end; end; if tonumber(ARGV[2]) > 0 then redis.call('zadd', KEYS[2], ARGV[2], ARGV[5]); else redis.call('zrem', KEYS[2], ARGV[5]); end; if tonumber(ARGV[3]) > 0 then redis.call('zadd', KEYS[3], ARGV[3], ARGV[5]); else redis.call('zrem', KEYS[3], ARGV[5]); end; local maxSize = tonumber(redis.call('hget', KEYS[8], 'max-size')); if maxSize ~= nil and maxSize ~= 0 then     local currentTime = tonumber(ARGV[1]);     local lastAccessTimeSe..., 8, cid-phone-qa, redisson__timeout__set:{cid-phone-qa}, redisson__idle__set:{cid-phone-qa}, redisson_map_cache_created:{cid-phone-qa}, redisson_map_cache_updated:{cid-phone-qa}, redisson__map_cache__last_access__set:{cid-phone-qa}, redisson_map_cache_removed:{cid-phone-qa}, {cid-phone-qa}:redisson_options, ...], codec=org.redisson.codec.MarshallingCodec]
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:361) ~[redisson-3.18.1.jar!/:3.18.1]
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decodeCommand(CommandDecoder.java:205) ~[redisson-3.18.1.jar!/:3.18.1]
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:144) ~[redisson-3.18.1.jar!/:3.18.1]
    at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandDecoder.decode(CommandDecoder.java:120) ~[redisson-3.18.1.jar!/:3.18.1]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:366) ~[netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar!/:4.1.52.Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a problem with how Redison is being used.

You are storing your 5 million pieces of data in a single Hash in Redis and then trying to expire them based on the *field*. Redis does support field-level expiration in Hashes. It can expire a key, but not elements within a key like fields in a Hash, members of a Set, or items in a List.

Redison provides this capability somehow. I'm not super familiar with it but I know it involves Lua scripts. My guess is that the Lua scripts aren't getting a chance to run because Redis is receiving data so quickly.

More importantly, however, I think storing that much data in a single Hash isn't—at least generally speaking—the best solution. That's a lot of data in one place. The key containing that data will exist on a single shard instead of being smeared across the cluster which will affect the horizontal scalability of your solution.

You would probably be better off storing each value in a String in Redis using a key name in Redis of `mapName` combined with what you are calling the `key`. This will use lots of key, which is good, as it allows the data to fan out across the cluster. And, it will allow *Redis* to handle the expiration instead of Redison.

Hope this helps!